# Parsing array of objects to range only does not parse all objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-apps-script

I need to parse an array of objects to a Google sheet.

I am using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052890/google-apps-script-how-to-copy-array-of-objects-to-range)

What I get is

| affiliations | corresponding | current_organization_id | first_name | last_name | orcid | raw_affiliation | researcher_id | state_code | corresponding | current_organization_id | first_name | last_name | orcid | raw_affiliation | researcher_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {city=My City, state_code=, city_id=123456.0, state=, country_code=XX, name=University of Bob, country=Country1, id=d.11111.0, raw_affiliation=This That, AA} |  | d.11111.0 | Joe | Aaaa | xxx-yyy-vvv-0000 | This That, AA | id.18738465.55 |  | TRUE | d.11111.0 | Joe | Aaaa | xxx-yyy-vvv-0000 | This That, AA | id.18738465.55 |
| {city_id=7891011.0, raw_affiliation=Something Something, BB, country=Country2, state_code=, name=University of Sally, city=Other Cite, state=, country_code=TT, id=d.22222.0} |  |  | Sally | Zzzz |  | Something Something, BB |  |  |  |  | Sally | Zzzz |  | Something Something, BB |  |

What I need

| city | city_id | country | country_code | id | name | raw_affiliation | state | state_code | corresponding | current_organization_id | first_name | last_name | orcid | raw_affiliation | researcher_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| My City | 123456 | Country1 | XX | d.11111.0 | University of Bob | This That, AA |  |  |  | d.11111.0 | Joe | Aaaa | xxx-yyy-vvv-0000 | This That, AA | id.18738465.55 |
| Other Cite | 7891011 | Country2 | TT | d.22222.0 | University of Sally | Something Something, BB |  |  |  |  | Sally | Zzzz |  | Something Something, BB |  |

`affiliations` is not parsing
Everything after `corresponding`  parses correctly

How to parse the `affiliations` array?

Google sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jXqlv2Jupdk0dTw0PSlDpGs7BlMVvGt6TjWSzIAlphI/edit?usp=sharing

```
function main() {
var data = [{'affiliations': [{'city': 'My City', 'city_id': 123456, 'country': 'Country1', 
                               'country_code': 'XX', 'id': 'd.11111.0', 'name': 'University of Bob',
                               'raw_affiliation': 'This That, AA', 'state': '', 'state_code': ''}], 
                               'corresponding': '', 'current_organization_id': 'd.11111.0',
                               'first_name': 'Joe', 'last_name': 'Aaaa', 'orcid': ['xxx-yyy-vvv-0000'], 
                               'raw_affiliation': ['This That, AA'], 'researcher_id': 'id.18738465.55'}, 
  
  {'affiliations': [{'city': 'Other Cite', 'city_id': 7891011, 'country': 'Country2', 'country_code': 'TT', 
                     'id': 'd.22222.0', 'name': 'University of Sally',
                     'raw_affiliation': 'Something Something, BB', 'state': '', 'state_code': ''}], 
                     'corresponding': '', 'current_organization_id': '', 'first_name': 'Sally', 
                     'last_name': 'Zzzz', 'orcid': [], 'raw_affiliation': ['Something Something, BB'], 
                     'researcher_id': ''}];

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var result = pattern1(data);
  var result = pattern2(data);

  sheet.getRange('a1').offset(0, 0, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
}

function pattern1(data){
  var ar = [];
  for (var i in data){
    for (var key in data[i]){
      ar.push([key, data[i][key]]);
    }
  }
  return ar;
}

function pattern2(data){
  var ar = [];
  var keys = [];
  var values = [];
  for (var i in data){
    for (var key in data[i]){
      if (i == 0) keys.push(key);
      values.push(data[i][key]);
    }
    if (i == 0){
      ar.push(keys);
      keys = [];
    }
    ar.push(values);
    values = [];
  }
  return ar;
}
```

Comment: The word affiliations is plural and the data structure is an array, designed to hold more than one thing.  So what do you want your output to look like if a given row of data has more than one affiliation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Workaround:

The way I've approached this is to create two loops; on that retrieves the object keys of each element of the `data` array and another one that retrieves its values. I've added an `if` condition to retrieve the keys and values of an object's value if it is another object, as is the case for `affiliations`

Do try this script:

```
function main() {
  var data = [{
    'affiliations': [{
      'city': 'My City', 'city_id': 123456, 'country': 'Country1',
      'country_code': 'XX', 'id': 'd.11111.0', 'name': 'University of Bob',
      'raw_affiliation': 'This That, AA', 'state': '', 'state_code': ''
    }],
    'corresponding': '', 'current_organization_id': 'd.11111.0',
    'first_name': 'Joe', 'last_name': 'Aaaa', 'orcid': ['xxx-yyy-vvv-0000'],
    'raw_affiliation': ['This That, AA'], 'researcher_id': 'id.18738465.55'
  },

  {
    'affiliations': [{
      'city': 'Other Cite', 'city_id': 7891011, 'country': 'Country2', 'country_code': 'TT',
      'id': 'd.22222.0', 'name': 'University of Sally',
      'raw_affiliation': 'Something Something, BB', 'state': '', 'state_code': ''
    }],
    'corresponding': '', 'current_organization_id': '', 'first_name': 'Sally',
    'last_name': 'Zzzz', 'orcid': [], 'raw_affiliation': ['Something Something, BB'],
    'researcher_id': ''
  }];

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var result = pattern1(data);

  sheet.getRange('a1').offset(0, 0, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
}

function pattern1(data) {
  var ar = [];
  for (let header in data[0]) {
    //This for loop gets the object keys
    if (typeof data[0][header][0] == 'object') {
      //If the object's value is another object, its keys are pushed to the array
      ar.push(Object.keys(data[0][header][0]))
    } else {
      ar[0].push(header);
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //This for loop gets the object values
    for (let header in data[i]) {
      if (typeof data[i][header][0] == 'object') {
        //If the object's value is another object, its values are pushed to the array
        ar.push(Object.values(data[i][header][0]))
      } else {
        ar[i + 1].push(data[i][header]);
      }
    }
  }
  return ar;
}
```

Do note that the script above works on the assumption that both objects on the `data` array have the same keys.

### References:

- [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)
- [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)